# How to derive the Clausius–Mossotti relation using Feynman diagrams?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, insulators

The [Clausius–Mossotti relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Mossotti_relation) is usually derived by assuming that a molecular in a crystal is surrounded by a spherical hole, or by the $- \frac{1}{3k^2} \delta(\boldsymbol{R})$ term in the dyadic Green's function: we have
$$
m \ddot{\boldsymbol{r}} = - m \omega_0^2 - m \gamma \boldsymbol{r} + e \left( \boldsymbol{E} + \frac{\boldsymbol{P}}{3 \epsilon_0} \right),
$$
and
$$
\boldsymbol{P} = N e \boldsymbol{r},
$$
and then it's easy to find the Clausius–Mossotti relation.

How can this relation be derived using Feynman diagrams, or in other words, what Feynman diagram resummation corresponds to this relation (considering the derivation above is much like a self-energy correction)?

Answer (score 3):

After several months I finally find out how. The C-M relation can't be obtained by integrating out electron propagators; what we need is actually integrating out microscopic electromagnetic fields.
The "II: general formalism" section in  https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.129.62 describes how to do so in a crystal.

Suppose we already have $\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{G'}}(\boldsymbol{q}, \omega)$ using, say, the epsilon code in BerkeleyGW, where $\boldsymbol{q}$ is restricted in the 1BZ. So now the relation between the screened field and the external electromagnetic scalar potential is
$$
V^{\text{screened}}(\boldsymbol{q}, \boldsymbol{G}, \omega) = 
\sum_{\boldsymbol{G}'} \epsilon^{-1}(\boldsymbol{q}, \omega)_{\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{G'}} V(\boldsymbol{q} + \boldsymbol{G'}) \delta_{\boldsymbol{G'} = 0} 
=  \epsilon^{-1}(\boldsymbol{q}, \omega)_{\boldsymbol{G} \boldsymbol{G'} = 0} V(\boldsymbol{q}) .
$$
Note that the external driving field is usually very smooth, since even the wave length of moderately soft X-ray is still above the typical magnitude of crystal constants, and thus $\boldsymbol{G}'$ is always zero.

On the other hand, what can be measured in $V^{\text{screened}}(\boldsymbol{q}, \boldsymbol{G}, \omega)$ is also macroscopic, so we have to set $\boldsymbol{G} = 0$ as well when deriving the experimentally observed electromagnetic field. So finally we find
$$
V^{\text{screened, measured}}(\boldsymbol{q}, \omega) =  \epsilon^{-1}(\boldsymbol{q}, \omega)_{\boldsymbol{G} = 0, \boldsymbol{G'} = 0} V(\boldsymbol{q}).
$$
In other words,
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon^{\text{measured}}} = \epsilon^{-1}(\boldsymbol{q}, \omega)_{\boldsymbol{G} = 0, \boldsymbol{G'} = 0} .
$$
Note that in the RHS we *first* take the inverse of the matrix and then take the (0, 0) component; since $\epsilon = 1 - v \chi$, this is equivalent to the following diagrammatic resummation:
$$
v(\boldsymbol{q}) + v(\boldsymbol{q}) \chi_{\boldsymbol{G} = 0, \boldsymbol{G}' = 0} v(\boldsymbol{q}) + 
v(\boldsymbol{q}) \chi_{\boldsymbol{G} = 0, \boldsymbol{G}' = 0} v(\boldsymbol{q} + \boldsymbol{G}') \chi_{\boldsymbol{G}', \boldsymbol{G}''=0} v(\boldsymbol{q}) + \cdots,
$$
where we integrate out intermediate microscopic fields $v(\boldsymbol{q} + \boldsymbol{G}')$.

So now we already have the most generalized formalism; the only rest thing to do is to get an explicit expression of $\chi$, which can be done  by the usual procedure used to derive the C-M relation.